# SDK for Facebook playable ads

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, ads

I want to make HTML playable ad for Facebook platform and show user avatar in it. Is it possible?

[According to docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/formats/playable-ad/) playable ad must not make any HTTP request.

So I just can't make any auth request from playable ad. Seems it does not support Facebook SDK either in this case

Also playable code in the ad must use the JavaScript function `FbPlayableAd.onCTAClick()` when the viewer interacts chooses the call-to-action.

Is there any reliable documentation for `FbPlayableAd` methods?

Answer (score 5):

Facebook doesn't appear to offer any helpful information beyond "you need to call the function".

When a playable is served, this `<script>` is injected into the `<head>`:

```
  const FbPlayableAd = {
    onCTAClick() {
      window.parent.postMessage("onCTAClick", "*");
    },
  };
```

To get around the missing `FBPlayableAd` object, solution here was to insert the following `<script>` after the `<body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.FBPlayableOnCTAClick = () => { 
  (typeof FbPlayableAd === 'undefined') ?
    alert('FBPlayableAd.onCTAClick') : FbPlayableAd.onCTAClick();
}
</script>
```

And then the CTA button has this onClick:

```
onClick={() => window.FBPlayableOnCTAClick()}
```

This allowed us to clear issues with Babel complaining about the missing FbPlayableAd, works fine in test, and functions fine when uploaded to Facebook's [Playable Preview](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/playable-preview/) tool.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer, Chris! **- FB developer:** we can add cool features, show user avatar right in the ad i.e. **- FB manager:** no, this feature is for 2030 year...