# Facebook playable ads in Google Web Designer

Tags: html, facebook

(Coding is very new to me, and I don't know much about it at all!)

I am attempting to make a playable facebook ad in Google Web Designer - it will be super simple.

I'm having trouble with this specification - **'FbPlayableAd.onCTAClick() implementation required.'** I'm not really sure where to add it in the code. Every time I upload the .html file to  facebook, that's the only bit that's missing.

Is someone able to tell me where to add it in the code view? Is it even possible? A step-by-step would be really useful.

Bonus points if there's a better platform to use for a super duper beginner!

EDIT: as per John's comment, I've attached an image of what the code looks like below:

(*if im correct, then it looks like Google Web Designer's event code is gwd-taparea. This all gets uploaded as a .html file here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/playable-preview/)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="Google Web Designer 11.0.2.0415">
  <meta name="template" content="Banner 3.0.0">
  <meta name="environment" content="gwd-dv360">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="gwdpage_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="13" data-exports-type="gwd-page">
  <link href="gwdpagedeck_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="14" data-exports-type="gwd-pagedeck">
  <link href="gwdgooglead_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="8" data-exports-type="gwd-google-ad">
  <link href="gwdimage_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="16" data-exports-type="gwd-image">
  <link href="gwdtaparea_style.css" rel="stylesheet" data-version="7" data-exports-type="gwd-taparea">
  <style type="text/css" id="gwd-lightbox-style">
    .gwd-lightbox {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css" id="gwd-text-style">
    p {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    h1 {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    h2 {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    h3 {
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .gwd-page-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .gwd-page-content {
      background-color: transparent;
      transform: perspective(1400px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .gwd-page-wrapper {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateZ(0px);
    }
    .gwd-page-size {
      width: 1080px;
      height: 1080px;
    }
    .gwd-image-1n37 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      left: 86px;
      top: 108px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    .gwd-rect-4vdd {
      position: absolute;
      left: 206.53px;
      top: 823.633px;
      width: 74.6495px;
      height: 74.6495px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: transparent;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    @keyframes gwd-gen-ubpsgwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
      0% {
        width: 74.6495px;
        height: 74.6495px;
        background-color: transparent;
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      16.6667% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      33.3333% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      50% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      66.6667% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      83.3333% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      100% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
    }
    #page1.gwd-play-animation .gwd-gen-ubpsgwdanimation {
      animation: 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running gwd-gen-ubpsgwdanimation_gwd-keyframes;
    }
    @keyframes gwd-gen-2ljmgwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
      0% {
        width: 74.6495px;
        height: 74.6495px;
        background-color: transparent;
        transform: translate3d(-64.8412px, 14.8877px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      16.6667% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      33.3333% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      50% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      66.6667% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      83.3333% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      100% {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(216, 6, 6);
        transform: translate3d(129px, 52px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
    }
    #page1.gwd-play-animation .gwd-gen-2ljmgwdanimation {
      animation: 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running gwd-gen-2ljmgwdanimation_gwd-keyframes;
    }
    .gwd-svg-1fha {
      transform: translate3d(-64.8412px, 14.8877px, 0px);
    }
    .gwd-taparea-1c0t {
      position: absolute;
      left: 472.78px;
      top: 838.563px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 140px;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    @keyframes gwd-gen-1loygwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
      0% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      16.6667% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 17px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      33.3333% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 17px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 17px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      66.6667% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 17px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      83.3333% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 17px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 17px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
    }
    #page1.gwd-play-animation .gwd-gen-1loygwdanimation {
      animation: 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running gwd-gen-1loygwdanimation_gwd-keyframes;
    }
    @keyframes gwd-gen-4zx8gwdanimation_gwd-keyframes {
      0% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      16.6667% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      33.3333% {
        transform: translate3d(250px, 57px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate3d(281.103px, -119.122px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      66.6667% {
        transform: translate3d(-13px, 79px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      83.3333% {
        transform: translate3d(487px, 54px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate3d(-46px, -51px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }
    }
    #page1.gwd-play-animation .gwd-gen-4zx8gwdanimation {
      animation: 3s linear 0s 1 normal forwards running gwd-gen-4zx8gwdanimation_gwd-keyframes;
    }
  </style>
  <script data-source="googbase_min.js" data-version="4" data-exports-type="googbase" src="googbase_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwd_webcomponents_v1_min.js" data-version="2" data-exports-type="gwd_webcomponents_v1" src="gwd_webcomponents_v1_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdpage_min.js" data-version="13" data-exports-type="gwd-page" src="gwdpage_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdpagedeck_min.js" data-version="14" data-exports-type="gwd-pagedeck" src="gwdpagedeck_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js" data-exports-type="gwd-google-ad" src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdgooglead_min.js" data-version="8" data-exports-type="gwd-google-ad" src="gwdgooglead_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdimage_min.js" data-version="16" data-exports-type="gwd-image" src="gwdimage_min.js"></script>
  <script data-source="gwdtaparea_min.js" data-version="7" data-exports-type="gwd-taparea" src="gwdtaparea_min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="support" src="gwd-events-support.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="handlers">
    gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action = function(event) {
      // GWD Predefined Function
      gwd.actions.gwdGoogleAd.exit('gwd-ad', 'CTA', 'https://www.google.com/', true, true, 'page1');
    };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="registration">
    // Support code for event handling in Google Web Designer
    // This script block is auto-generated. Please do not edit!
    gwd.actions.events.registerEventHandlers = function(event) {
      gwd.actions.events.addHandler('gwd-taparea_1', 'action', gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action, false);
    };
    gwd.actions.events.deregisterEventHandlers = function(event) {
      gwd.actions.events.removeHandler('gwd-taparea_1', 'action', gwd.auto_Gwd_taparea_1Action, false);
    };
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", gwd.actions.events.registerEventHandlers);
    document.addEventListener("unload", gwd.actions.events.deregisterEventHandlers);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <gwd-google-ad id="gwd-ad" polite-load="">
    <gwd-metric-configuration>
      <gwd-metric-event source="gwd-taparea_1" event="tapareaexit" metric="" exit="Exit"></gwd-metric-event>
    </gwd-metric-configuration>
    <gwd-pagedeck class="gwd-page-container" id="pagedeck">
      <gwd-page id="page1" class="gwd-page-wrapper gwd-page-size gwd-lightbox" data-gwd-width="1080px" data-gwd-height="1080px">
        <div class="gwd-page-content gwd-page-size">
          <gwd-image id="how_to" source="assets/how to.png" scaling="stretch" class="gwd-image-1n37 gwd-gen-4zx8gwdanimation"></gwd-image>
          <svg data-gwd-shape="rectangle" class="gwd-rect-4vdd gwd-gen-ubpsgwdanimation"></svg>
          <svg data-gwd-shape="rectangle" class="gwd-rect-4vdd gwd-gen-2ljmgwdanimation gwd-svg-1fha"></svg>
          <gwd-taparea id="gwd-taparea_1" class="gwd-taparea-1c0t gwd-gen-1loygwdanimation"></gwd-taparea>
        </div>
      </gwd-page>
    </gwd-pagedeck>
    <gwd-exit metric="CTA" url="https://www.google.com/"></gwd-exit>
  </gwd-google-ad>
  <script type="text/javascript" id="gwd-init-code">
    (function() {
      var gwdAd = document.getElementById('gwd-ad');

      /**
       * Handles the DOMContentLoaded event. The DOMContentLoaded event is
       * fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed.
       */
      function handleDomContentLoaded(event) {

      }

      /**
       * Handles the WebComponentsReady event. This event is fired when all
       * custom elements have been registered and upgraded.
       */
      function handleWebComponentsReady(event) {
        // Start the Ad lifecycle.
        setTimeout(function() {
          gwdAd.initAd();
        }, 0);
      }

      /**
       * Handles the event that is dispatched after the Ad has been
       * initialized and before the default page of the Ad is shown.
       */
      function handleAdInitialized(event) {}

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
        handleDomContentLoaded, false);
      window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady',
        handleWebComponentsReady, false);
      window.addEventListener('adinitialized',
        handleAdInitialized, false);
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the applicable HTML that you have attempted to upload to Facebook.

Comment: @JohnH Thanks John - have just included it all! Sorry, I'm not well versed in HTML at all!

Comment: it's like here is your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411016/sdk-for-facebook-playable-ads